# iOS UI Automation: ошибка при assert'e текстового поля через CTAssertTrue

Tags: ios, swift, ui, uiautomation

Во время автоматизации кейса по смене email’a пользователя возникла проблема с ассертом элемента «текстовое поле, выделенное красным цветом» - скрин во вложениях).
Как решить данную проблему?

[text field highlighted in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7VTH.png) ".

**Как пробовали решить проблему:**

- через функцию "waitForText":

```
func waitForText(name: String) {
        waitForElementToAppear(app.staticTexts[name])
    }
```

функция "waitForText" является частным случаем функции"waitForElementToAppear":

```
func waitForElementToAppear(_ element: XCUIElement) -> Bool{
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    let expectat = expectation(for: predicate, evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)
    let result = XCTWaiter().wait(for: [expectat], timeout: 20)
    return result == .completed
}
```

- через функцию "waitForTextShort":

```
func waitForTextShort(name: String) {
        waitForElementToAppearShort(app.staticTexts[name])
    }
```

функция "waitForTextShort" вляется частным случаем функции "waitForElementToAppearShort":

```
func waitForElementToAppearShort(_ element: XCUIElement) -> Bool{
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
        let expectat = expectation(for: predicate, evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)
        let result = XCTWaiter().wait(for: [expectat], timeout: 5)
        return result == .completed
    }
```

- через CTAssertTrue:

```
CTAssertTrue (app.staticTexts.element (match: .any, id: "Enter your email address"). exists)
```

Поиск элементов с помощью рекордера UI тестов отображает только поле для ввода, но не его наследников.

Выгрузка элементов через **po app.staticTexts** также не дает нужных результатов:

```
 StaticText, {{16.0, 130.0}, {288.0, 16.5}}, tag: "Enter your email address"
```

Используемые локаторы:

```
app.tables/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.staticTexts["Enter your email address"]/*[[".cells.staticTexts[\"Enter your email address\"]",".staticTexts[\"Enter your email address\"]"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/.tap()
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена: достаточно попросить разработчика накинуть на плашку id, и далее - ассертить ее :)